# Flow: Pass sObject Variable to and from a subflow

Tags: visual-workflow

**Is it possible to pass sObject record variables from one flow to another?** For example, if I provide the user the ability to jump into a screen subflow to create an Account or Contact (which I would store in an `sAccount` or `sContact` variable with "output" enabled. Could I then receive that from my calling flow?

I assumed this was possible from everything I've read, but at the moment when I attempt it like so...
[image]

I can can close the component screen, but when I save the Flow I get the following error message:

> ***An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 2129314187-211745 (-944130218)***

[image]

Is this simply a bug or am I misunderstanding how this needs to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of scouring the interwebs, with no reason to believe this should not work, I finally uncovered why I was getting this error. In short, it was because of a `private` setting on my `sContact` sObject variable from the main Flow.

The reason this was not easily detected, my `sContact` variable was created from a "Get Records" component like so. Unfortunately when using the "Automatically store all field" feature there is no way to add the "input/output" classification (yet...[vote here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000U4pKQAS))
[image]